# How to fetch comments from pubnub via periscope credentials?

Tags: pubnub

Till now, I understand that we can view messages from any channel using `history()` command in pubnub.

I am using Periscope API to fetch broadcasts.It uses pubnub for comments.

I have `subscriber-key`,`auth-token` and 'channel-name'.

**Can I fetch comments(or messages) for a particular channel ?**

My trials:

---

I tried using history command but it resulted :

---

```
Array
(
    [status] => 403
    [service] => Access Manager
    [error] => 1
    [message] => Forbidden
    [payload] => Array
        (
            [channels] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'my_channel'
                )

        )

)
```

I would add that this channel doesnot belong to my own pubnub application.I accessed it externally. 
Now I found out that read access must be granted on 'subscriber_key' or 'channel' so that a user can access this. But I am pretty sure they have granted. 
Is there any method to check permissions for 'subscriber_key' ?

Comment: I have replied to PubNub support. Can you follow up ..

Answer (score 1):

Solved !!

For an external channel or subscriber, you need to pass auth_key values as well while initiating pubnub instance.

> var pubnub = PUBNUB({
>       subscribe_key: 'subkey_value', 
>       auth_key: 'auth_key_value'   });

Running any command will not generate auth error.
Then you have the whole gem of punub !